# HAProxy redirect only top level subdomain?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I want HAProxy to redirect `lan.example.com`, but not `*.lan.example.com` (or any subdomains of `lan.example.com`

The rule I have in my frontend to choose the backend is currently:

```
use_backend lan-backend-tcp-http if { hdr(host) -i lan.example.com }
```

Which currently redirects `lan.example.com` and all subdomains to that.  I just want the top level of that subdomain.

Comment: Are you able to see what the host header looks like on each request? Is it `lan.example.com` and then for example `other.lan.example.com`? If so, then I can suggest an answer.

Comment: I just tested out your example config and it works for me as expected. Only requests with the host header `lan.example.com` are going to the backend. `test.lan.example.com` goes to no backend. Could you help me understand the issue you're having?